# Retrieving parameters from a URL

Tags: python, django, parsing, url

Given a URL like the following, how can I parse the value of the query parameters? For example, in this case I want the value of `some_key` .

```
/some_path?some_key=some_value'
```

I am using Django in my environment; is there a method on the `request` object that could help me?

I tried using `self.request.get('some_key')` but it is not returning the value `some_value` as I had hoped.

Answer (score 438, accepted):

This is not specific to Django, but for Python in general. For a Django specific answer, [see this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23615281/102401) from @jball037

**Python 2:**

```py
import urlparse

url = 'https://www.example.com/some_path?some_key=some_value'
parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
captured_value = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['some_key'][0]

print captured_value
```

**Python 3:**

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

url = 'https://www.example.com/some_path?some_key=some_value'
parsed_url = urlparse(url)
captured_value = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)['some_key'][0]

print(captured_value)
```

`parse_qs` returns a list. The `[0]` gets the first item of the list so the output of each script is `some_value`

[Here's the 'parse_qs' documentation for Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs)

Comment: In python3 `import urllib.parse as urlparse`

Comment: Note that `parse_qs` will return you a list object. You need to get the first element of it if you want a string `urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['def'][0]`

Comment: Note that if url contain '#' character just like this: http://foo.appspot.com/#/abc?def=ghi, you must disallow fragments: `urlparse(url, allow_fragments=False)`, otherwise query will return empty str.

Comment: Py3 docs: [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urlparse#urllib.parse.urlparse); [parse_qs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=parse_qs#urllib.parse.parse_qs). Py2 docs: [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urlparse.html?highlight=urlparse#urlparse.urlparse); [parse_qs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urlparse.html?highlight=parse_qs#urlparse.parse_qs).

Comment: in python3, must use `from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs` and `parse_qs(parsed.query)`

Comment: @FrancescoFrassinelli it's valid. `urlparse.urlparse(url)` --> `urlparse(url)`

Comment: @Winand you are right of course. I do not know why that evening I wrote that :) Thanks.

Comment: What happens if the URL Is not valid (just a string) ... oR ... if the param is not present?

Comment: Getting AttributeError: 'ParseResult' object has no attribute 'decode', unsolved

Answer (score 91):

I'm shocked this solution isn't on here already. Use:

```
request.GET.get('variable_name')
```

This will "get" the variable from the "GET" dictionary, and return the 'variable_name' value if it exists, or a None object if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I can't get this to work.  Maybe some more details.  How are you getting request?  Is this python3 compatible?

Comment: @ggedde this answer (like the question) is for django, it is a django request object. if you are not using django, use one of the other answers.

Comment: def parse_category_page(self, response):
                product_id = response.GET.get('number') doesnt work neither does request

Comment: I'm shocked that someone actually added this answer and has so many likes (just kidding ;) ). One thing is getting query params from a random URL, and a very different thing is getting those params from inside an endpoint that you are serving using Django or another framework. This answer is in the case your URL is precisely the one you are serving with Django. The question is about some random internet URL... should parse it instead.

Answer (score 70):

for Python > 3.4

```
from urllib import parse
url = 'http://foo.appspot.com/abc?def=ghi'
query_def=parse.parse_qs(parse.urlparse(url).query)['def'][0]
```

Comment: Best way to do it IMO. Doesn't need extra packages and works A+ on Python 3.5.

Answer (score 65):

```
import urlparse
url = 'http://example.com/?q=abc&p=123'
par = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(url).query)

print par['q'][0], par['p'][0]
```

Answer (score 35):

There is a new library called furl. I find this library to be most pythonic for doing url algebra. 
To install:

```
pip install furl
```

Code:

```
from furl import furl
f = furl("/abc?def='ghi'") 
print f.args['def']
```

Comment: Great library! Didn't know about it but works like a charm :)

Comment: :) I have wasted my share of time trying to make urlparse work for me. No more.

Answer (score 21):

I know this is a bit late but since I found myself on here today, I thought that this might be a useful answer for others.

```
import urlparse
url = 'http://example.com/?q=abc&p=123'
parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
params = urlparse.parse_qsl(parsed.query)
for x,y in params:
    print "Parameter = "+x,"Value = "+y
```

With parse_qsl(), "Data are returned as a list of name, value pairs."

Answer (score 8):

In pure Python:

```
def get_param_from_url(url, param_name):
    return [i.split("=")[-1] for i in url.split("?", 1)[-1].split("&") if i.startswith(param_name + "=")][0]
```

Answer (score 7):

The url you are referring is a query type and I see that the request object supports a method called [arguments](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html#Request_arguments) to get the query arguments. You may also want try `self.request.get('def')` directly to get your value from the object..

Answer (score 6):

```
def getParams(url):
    params = url.split("?")[1]
    params = params.split('=')
    pairs = zip(params[0::2], params[1::2])
    answer = dict((k,v) for k,v in pairs)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This should not be necessary inside a webapp.

Answer (score 4):

The urlparse module provides everything you need:

```py
urlparse.parse_qs()
```

Comment: Does this answer provide anything not provided by other answers?

Answer (score 4):

There's not need to do any of that. Only with

```
self.request.get('variable_name')
```

Notice that I'm not specifying the method (GET, POST, etc). This is [well documented](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass#Request_get) and [this is an example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/handlingforms)

The fact that you use Django templates doesn't mean the handler is processed by Django as well

Answer (score 3):

```
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

import cgi
print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
i = int(form.getvalue('a'))+int(form.getvalue('b'))
print i
```

Answer (score 3):

Most answers here suggest using [`parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) to parse an URL string. This method always returns the values as a list (not directly as a string) because a parameter can appear multiple times, e.g.:

`http://example.com/?foo=bar&foo=baz&bar=baz`

Would return:

`{'foo': ['bar', 'baz'], 'bar' : ['baz']}`

This is a bit inconvenient because in most cases you're dealing with an URL that doesn't have the same parameter multiple times. This function returns the first value by default, and only returns a list if there's more than one element.

```py
from urllib import parse

def parse_urlargs(url):
    query = parse.parse_qs(parse.urlparse(url).query)
    return {k:v[0] if v and len(v) == 1 else v for k,v in query.items()}
```

For example, `http://example.com/?foo=bar&foo=baz&bar=baz` would return:

`{'foo': ['bar', 'baz'], 'bar': 'baz'}`

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice library w3lib.url

```
from w3lib.url import url_query_parameter
url = "/abc?def=ghi"
print url_query_parameter(url, 'def')
ghi
```

Answer (score 2):

Parsing it in raw python:

```
path = '/some_path?k1=v1&k2=v2&k3=v3'
_, query_string = path.split('?')
params  = dict(param.split('=') for param in query_string.split('&'))
print(params)
```

Output:

```
{'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Btw, I was having issues using parse_qs() and getting empty value parameters and learned that you have to pass a second optional parameter 'keep_blank_values' to return a list of the parameters in a query string that contain no values. It defaults to false. Some crappy written APIs require parameters to be present even if they contain no values

```
for k,v in urlparse.parse_qs(p.query, True).items():
  print k
```

Answer (score 0):

> parameters = dict([part.split('=') for part in
>   get_parsed_url[4].split('&')])

This one is simple. The variable parameters will contain a dictionary of all the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I see there isn't an answer for users of Tornado:

```
key = self.request.query_arguments.get("key", None)
```

This method must work inside an handler that is derived from:

```
tornado.web.RequestHandler
```

None is the answer this method will return when the requested key can't be found. This saves you some exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to mess with additional libraries. Simple ways suggested here didn't work out either. Finally, not on the request object, but I could get a GET parameter w/o all that hassle via `self.GET.get('XXX')`:

```
...
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(SomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['XXX'] = self.GET.get('XXX')
...
```

Python 2.7.18, Django 1.11.20

Answer (score 0):

NOT using Django and tried on Python 3.9. It can also be retrieved using the below code snippet in the handler:

considering URL as-

```
http://localhost:8081/api/v1/users?query_key=abcdef12345
```

and handler method as:

```
@routes.get('/api/v1/users')
async def handler_users(request):
    query_key = request.url.query['query_key']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only request.GET.get() method

urls.py:

```
    path('some_path', views.func),
```

views.py:

```
def func(request):
    some_key = request.GET.get('some_key', None)
    ...
```