# Parse query part from url

Tags: python, urlparse

I want to parse query part from url, this is my code to do this:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
>>> url = '/?param1&param2=2'
>>> parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)
>>> {'param2': ['23']}
```

This code looks good, but "parse_qs" method loses query parameters like "param1" or "param1=". Can I parse query part with stantard library and save all parameters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving parameters from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074803/retrieving-parameters-from-a-url)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You want:

```
from urlparse import parse_qs, urlparse

parse_qs(urlparse(url).query, keep_blank_values=True)
# {'param2': ['2'], 'param1': ['']}
```

Comment: For Python 3 the imports are `from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse`