# How can I extract words from url?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am using Python 3.6

This is my url address.

[http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/mycar/popup/mycarChart_B.php?car_number=35두8475&tbl=cyber&cno=651451](http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/mycar/popup/mycarChart_B.php?car_number=35%EB%91%908475&tbl=cyber&cno=651451)

I would like to extract "35두8475" and "651451".
How can I do this?

Below is my code but it keeps returning an error message, 'function' object has no attribute 'parse_qs'
Please give me some advice.

Thanks.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
url = 'http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/mycar/popup/mycarChart_B.php?car_number=35두8475&tbl=cyber&cno=651451'
parsed = urlparse(url)
print(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed)['no'])
```

Comment: can you please show your effort?

Comment: How can you judge my effort?? I have been trying this for last couple of hours with a number of trial.

Comment: I asked you to share your code.

Comment: I absolutely misunderstood you comment. Missing upload my code was totally my fault. I uploaded it. The problem is that my editor doesn't recognize ".parse_qs" even though I import urlparse ("from urllib.parse import urlparse")

Comment: I figured out!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

```
import urlparse
url = 'http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/mycar/popup/mycarChart_B.php?car_number=35두8475&tbl=cyber&cno=651451'
parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
print urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['car_number']
```

Check [Retrieving parameters from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074803/retrieving-parameters-from-a-url)

Comment: I am using python 3.6. When I tried with your code, it keeps returning an error message, "No module named 'urlparse'" even though I changed my code like below:

Comment: from urllib.parse import urlparse
url = 'http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/mycar/popup/mycarChart_B.php?car_number=35두8475&tbl=cyber&cno=651451'
parsed = urlparse(url)
print(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed)['no'])

Comment: I figured out!! Thanks!!

Comment: Yes urllib on python3 is a bit different.This process to get query parameters is quite easy since it is standard GET request.