# How to use regex & python to parse lat/long from a url?

Tags: python, regex

I have the url: `https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=44.864505,-93.44873&z=18&t=m&hl=en&gl=US&mapclient=apiv3`

I wanted to extract the lat/long from the url, so that I have `44.864505,-93.44873`.

So far I have `(^[maps?ll=]*$|(?<=\?).*)*` which gives me `ll=44.864505,-93.44873&z=18&t=m&hl=en&gl=US&mapclient=apiv3`
 but this needs impovement. I have been trying to use [pythex](https://pythex.org/) to work this out, but I am stuck.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074803/retrieving-parameters-from-a-url

Comment: Why not split the string by the 'll=' and '&' if that is common nomenclature

    url = 'https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=44.864505,-93.44873&z=18&t=m&hl=en&gl=US&mapclient=apiv3'
    lat,long = url.split("ll=")[1].split("&")[0].split(",")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't use regex, I'd use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html)

For Python2:

```
import urlparse

url = 'https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=44.864505,-93.44873&z=18&t=m&hl=en&gl=US&mapclient=apiv3'
parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
params = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)

print(params['ll'])
```

prints:

```
['44.864505,-93.44873']
```

For Python3 ([`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)) :

```
import urllib.parse as urlparse

url = 'https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=44.864505,-93.44873&z=18&t=m&hl=en&gl=US&mapclient=apiv3'
parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
params = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)

print(params['ll'])
```

prints:

```
['44.864505,-93.44873']
```