# Extract a string from a url field in python or SQL

Tags: python, sql

URL example = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?newreg=12f6529a5b3449c3be1d14458a4657ef'

i want to return the barcode number after ''newreg' in the URL. The string is not same len everytime

Would appreciate any help here

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving parameters from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074803/retrieving-parameters-from-a-url)

Comment: Do you have any code that shows what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use simple split() ?

```
url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?newreg=12f6529a5b3449c3be1d14458a4657ef'
barcode = url.split('=')[-1]
```

Hope this helps!