# catch certain text in file.txt and parse into python file as input

Tags: python

how do i extract certain word in bold below and store the value as input? i managed to get url value as it has referer: text, i would like take value that starting from 1st until it meet '=' sign that is **username** and continue to catch text start from '&' until '=' which is **password**?

> **username**=hello&**password**=test1

Comment: Is it always like 5? Is the value always `username` and `password`?

Comment: @HarshalParekh it always in line 5 but the username and password is variables/changeable. that why i want to get text in line 5 from 1st to '=' sign and continue from '&' sign to '=' sign..that store as 2 variables respectively..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving parameters from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074803/retrieving-parameters-from-a-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i, line in enumerate(f):  
    # line 5
    if i == 4:
        # get the value from the start of the string to the first "="
        username = line[:line.index('=')]

        # get the value starting from the "&" to the second "="
        password = line[line.index('&') + 1:line.index('=', line.index('=') + 1)]

        print(username, password)
```

More on [index](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.index) and [substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/how-do-i-get-a-substring-of-a-string-in-python).

Comment: i know if we have static 'username' and 'password' text, but 'username' and 'password' are not static.But 'username' sometime maybe can be uname' and so on..

Comment: Then you can use the same logic on line 5. You can check my edit.

Comment: thank you.....it works