# Python | Method getting uri parameter using key and returning value

Tags: python, uri

we are trying to create a function that accepts and uri para key and returns an URI param value.

```
/webshop/&onderdeel=shop&r_id=108&p_id=317
/webshop/?onderdeel=shop&r_id=108&p_id=317
example.com/webshop/?onderdeel=shop&r_id=108&p_id=317
https://example.com/webshop/?onderdeel=shop&r_id=108&p_id=317
?onderdeel=shop&r_id=108&p_id=317
```

This function captures som examples of above, but not all

**Question**: is there 1 method that captures all  examples? (e.g. we need the value for p_id)

(and while are at it, is there also 1 method that returns all key value pairs?)

```
# get url param
@staticmethod
def get_uri_param(url, param=""):
    try: 
        return parse.parse_qs(parse.urlparse(url).query)[param][0]
    except:
        return None
```

I was trying this below from [Retrieving parameters from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074803/retrieving-parameters-from-a-url) but this is not working

Practising here [on TIO](https://tio.run/##nZDNDoIwEITP8hQ9gSSmSDxoSIgn4wt4M4agXaRJS8u2Rn16bAViPPlz2pnMN3sYfbe1ahZdx6VWaMkFheBHqks0QErj/VMHFSr5ng6NpylaE7jQkJzso@QKR1MrnYSqYYAMQOTeh1hwlqfzVai9WKTLaPaC11/AcCulFkBPSv7Uq63VJkuSf/ufmUNQKfT7EN74Y7JgopE3duoM3W529Ax2Gnk@imOX@dWYm2scmI7CFxzAK9LTw0P3b3g4Dt4LRtsL4D3e9/Qh7roH)

```
import urllib.parse as urlparse
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
urls = ['/webshop/&onderdeel=shop&r_id=108&p_id=317','/webshop/?onderdeel=shop&r_id=108&p_id=317','example.com/webshop/?onderdeel=shop&r_id=108&p_id=317','https://example.com/webshop/?onderdeel=shop&r_id=108&p_id=317','?onderdeel=shop&r_id=108&p_id=317']
for url in urls:
    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    if 'p_id' in url:
        print(parse_qs(parsed.query)['p_id'])
```

Comment: `urllib.parse.parse_qs("actual_url")["pid"][0]`?

Answer (score 1):

Thx to Abdul

Tested on array of data and works for all situations.

```
# get url param
@staticmethod
def get_1_uri_param(url, param=""):
    try:
        if param in url:
            return parse_qs(url)[param][0]
    except:
        return url

# get all url params as array data
@staticmethod
def get_all_uri_params(url):
    try:
        return parse_qs(url)
    except:
        return []
```