# Get session ID of URL with python

Tags: python, url

I have the following URL after checkout -

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/register/?session_id=cs_test_a1LrWp5FzCp18vnxTXyQVwpCVwBE7HL0rkbyvea8i9QCVIJoxqIXxMbDx9
```

I would like to extract the session ID part of this url to use -

cs_test_a1LrWp5FzCp18vnxTXyQVwpCVwBE7HL0rkbyvea8i9QCVIJoxqIXxMbDx9

I know I can use `session_id = url.rsplit('=', 1)[-1]` to split it from the url but how do I get python to read the current url?

I have tried `path_info = request.META.get('PATH_INFO')` but that just reads '/register/'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving parameters from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074803/retrieving-parameters-from-a-url)

Comment: In those examples the url is hardcoded in. I can split the url fine, it is the method of getting the current url that I can't work out

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this with:

```
url = request.META['QUERY_STRING']
session_id = url.rsplit('=', 1)[-1]
```